# S3 bucket: Encountered unsupported property NonCurrentVersionTransition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I want to add this S3 lifecycle rule to CloudFormation template:

```yaml
          - Prefix: "dumps/"
            TagFilters:
              - Key: tag
                Value: value
            ExpirationInDays: 21
            NonCurrentVersionTransitions:
              - TransitionInDays: 3
                StorageClass: "GLACIER"
            Status: Enabled
```

ERROR :

> Encountered unsupported property NonCurrentVersionTransitions

Both properties are unsupported :

NonCurrentVersionTransitions

NonCurrentVersionTransition

I followed this doc :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig-rule.html#cfn-s3-bucket-rule-tagfilters

Thanks for your help ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a typo problem? CloudFormation doc says `NoncurrentVersionTransitions`, not `NonCurrentVersionTransitions`